# How to replace an ```img``` tag inside a ```td``` tag using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse a webpage filled with tables using `python3.8.7` and `BeautifulSoup4.9.3` so I can display it on a telegram channel. I can get all the tables necessary from the webpage but deep inside those tables there are `td` tags that contain `img` tags with `src` of a star that need to be replace with  a `p` tag. These is the code thus far:

```py
import pickle
import bs4 as bs

v_file = open('data/pickled_data/pickled_v', 'rb')
v_pickled = pickle.load(v_file)

v_soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(v_pickled.content, "html5lib")
all_tbls = v_soup.find_all('table')
```

I've tried replacing the image -- aka `star_image` -- as below, but it returns `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace_with'`:

```py
url_2_check = "https://i.imgur.com/ffIvqVj.png"

for table in all_tbls:
    for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
        for td in table.find_all('td'):
            for star_image in td.find_all('img'):
                if star_image['src'] == url_2_check:
                    p_tag = v_soup.new_tag('p')
                    p_tag.string = ":star:"
                    td.star_image.replace_with(p_tag)
```

Then I tried it as below, but it returns `ValueError: Cannot replace one element with another when the element to be replaced is not part of a tree`:

```py
for table in all_tbls:
    for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
        for td in table.find_all('td'):
            for star_image in td.find_all('img'):
                if star_image['src'] == url_2_check:
                    p_tag = v_soup.new_tag('p')
                    p_tag.string = ":star:"
                    td.replace_with(p_tag)
```

I can't seem to be able to figure out what I'm doing wrong, can anybody please help?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share URL?

Comment: @AndrejKesely https://xxviptips.blogspot.com/

Comment: Do you want to replace the stars with a number?

Comment: No, I want to replace it with a text that says :star:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse the data from table, you can use following example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://xxviptips.blogspot.com/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "lxml")

for t in soup.select("table"):
    rows = t.select("tr")
    league = rows[0].get_text(strip=True)
    match, info1, info2 = [
        td.get_text(strip=True) for td in rows[1].select("td")
    ]
    rate_star = " ".join([":star:"] * len(rows[2].select("img")))

    print(
        "{:<35} {:<35} {:<10} {:<10} {:<50}".format(
            league, match, info1, info2, rate_star
        )
    )
```

Prints:

```
Eng. Premier League - 19:00 GMT     Fulham - Burnley                    under 3.5  1.30       :star: :star: :star: :star:                       
Spanish Liga Primera- 19:00 GMT     Betis - Granada CF                  over 1.5   1.30       :star: :star: :star:                              
Spanish Liga Segunda- 19:00 GMT     Gijon - Lugo                        under 2.5  1.44       :star: :star: :star:                              
Spanish Liga Segunda- 17:00 GMT     Rayo Vallecano - Leganes            DC - 1/X   1.30       :star: :star: :star:                              
German Bundesliga 2- 16:00 GMT      Holstein Kiel - Hannover            DC - 1/X   1.25       :star: :star: :star: :star:                       
German Bundesliga 2- 18:30 GMT      Hamburger SV - Nurnberg             under 4.5  1.22       :star: :star: :star: :star:                       
Italian Serie B - 12:00 GMT         Pescara - Salernitana               away win   1.27       :star: :star: :star:                              
Italian Serie B- 12:00 GMT          Empoli - Lecce                      DC - 1/X   1.31       :star: :star: :star: :star:                       
Romanian Liga 1- 18:30 GMT          FCSB - FC Clinceni                  home win   1.27       :star: :star: :star: :star:                       
Romanian Liga 1- 13:45 GMT          FC Voluntari - Chindia Targoviste   under 2.5  1.38       :star: :star: :star:                              
Portuguese Prim. Liga- 19:15 GMT    Porto - Sporting Farense            home win   1.33       :star: :star: :star: :star:                       
Portuguese Prim. Liga - 17:00 GMT   Portimonense - Moreirense           under 3.5  1.25       :star: :star: :star: :star:
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Mind if I ask you for some explanations for the code?

Comment: @GaddBWeldesenbet The page is strucured that each match is in separate `<table>`. In each `<table>` there are 4 rows (`<tr>`). I get league name from first row, match name from second row etc.

Comment: I understood that, I didn't know about the ```select()``` in BeautifulSoup...I should RTFM.
Thank you very much.